# Available space left on drive - WinAPI - Windows CE

Tags: winapi, pinvoke, windows-ce, diskspace

I've forgotten the WinAPI call to find out how much space is remaining on a particular drive and pinvoke.net isn't giving me any love.
It's compact framework by the way, so I figure coredll.dll.

Can anyone with a better memory jog mine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetDiskFreeSpaceEx.html). That links to pinvoke.net's desktop page; simply replace `kernel32` with `coredll`.

Unfortunately `System.IO.DriveInfo` is not present on Compact Framework. It doesn't quite fit with Windows CE's Unix-style singly-rooted tree.

Comment: Nice one. I shall update pinvoke.net to show this call is available from coredll.dll.