# getting the free space on the device - Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to get the free space on the device and the external storage?

I need to know if the user has enough space to download the files from server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409069/getting-the-size-free-total-of-a-windows-mobile-phone-drive-using-c-sharp

Comment: I tried the methods described in the link, but they do not work on windows phone 8 (OR at least I couldn't get them to work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this possibly what you are looking for?

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().AvailableFreeSpace;
```

According to msdn [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.availablefreespace%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) it

> Gets a value that represents the amount of free space available for isolated storage.